# Request.IsAuthenticated returns false when using Intelligencia rewriter for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, urlrewriter

I'am using Intelligencia rewriter for ASP.NET. Now I added forms authentication to the project and for some reason on the seo friendly pages (.html) the Request.IsAuthenticated property is always false. I can see that the cookie is created fine with fiddler. When i visit any other .aspx page I can see that the same property is true. Obviously this is related to the rewriter, however I could not find any solution for it at all.

Answer (score 1):

I spent quite some time on this reading all the solutions out there on the Internet, but in my case it finally boiled down to being a missing web.config setting :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/User/LogIn" timeout="2880" />  
</authentication>
```

If there's no authentication specified, no authentication will be used although you might have a auth cookie present.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Troubleshooting Forms Authentication](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910439) and the [FormsAuthLogger](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6587).

For reference, Microsoft has a detailed article on [what are the moving parts and processes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443).